# Something changed recently in highcharts.js exporting

Tags: highcharts

Bit of an edge case situation here. A client requested some highly customized and printable PDF's be exported from his highcharts based dashboard. I pulled it off by combining some svg exported from illustrator with multiple charts and using a method provided on the old highcharts forum, sent the resulting  element to the exporter hosted at highcharts.com

I completed the work about a month ago and it was working perfectly. The other day the pdf's just started going nuts. They're cropped to 400x300, substituting fonts, the legends are blurry etc. 
Here is a link to a working pdf I got back on 4 April
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14440432/chart%20%285%29.pdf

And here's a jsfiddle demonstrating what's happening now.
       http://jsfiddle.net/JoelStransky/AyPUc/2/
    `never mind this code;`
    `just trying to get the jsfiddle link to post`

This gives a strong suspicion that something changed in the hosted exporters settings. I'd love to be wrong about that but I've not touched these files since. At this point, I just need a fix. Please help.

Comment: Yes, exporting has changed, take a look: http://docs.highcharts.com/#export-module

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not sure what you're suggesting. Do you know what's wrong or are you just pointing out that a change happened sometime in recent history that may or may not be relevant to my problem?

Comment: Regarding widths and heights for charts - this has changed so it's related to your issue. Could you create example in jsFiddle with live example? Not with some generated SVG, which could be easily changed.

Comment: Most of the information is read from json and fed to my chart objects, the rest of the page is using mustache templates. It will be difficult for me to create a jsfiddle using this process but I'll try. In the mean time, the svg node in my sample is the exact result of my current process. I suppose creating a simple test case that recreates the problem is the next step here but any insight on how the export service has changed might point me in the right direction. Thanks